# Axios GET request - how params should work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I would like to clarify the aim of "params" as an argument of axios.get.

I am implementing a search bar in my React App, but I am not able to filter the results through **params**.

Based on few tutorials I followed, **params** should help me filter through the responses I get from the API call. For example, considering one of the elements contained in the response from the GitHub Jobs API, I would expect that if I pass as **params** `params: {location: "Austin, TX"}` the final response should contain all the elements with that specific location.

The examples in the axios guide refer to a filtering based on the **ID** for example, so I infer this should be the same for any other key of the elements returned by the response.

In my app I have a select feature with all the locations available in the data. When one is selected it updates the `filters` variable which becomes, for example, `{location: "Austin, TX"}`. This is the value I pass, but it still does not filter the results.
As you can see below, I have a SearchForm.js where I select a location from a dropdown list, it goes into the handleParamChange in App.js which calls the useFetchJobs.js function with the filters and the result of the API call should come back.

```
useFetchJobs.js

const BASE_URL =
    'https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=https://jobs.github.com/positions.json';

function useFetchJobs(filters) {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
        jobs: [],
        locations: [],
        loading: true,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const cancelToken1 = axios.CancelToken.source();

        axios
            .get(BASE_URL, {
                params: { ...filters },
            })
            .then((res) => {
                var loc = res.data.map((item) => item.location);
                loc = [...new Set(loc)];
                loc.sort();

                dispatch({
                    type: ACTIONS.GET_DATA,
                    payload: { jobs: res.data, locations: loc },
                });
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                if (axios.isCancel(e)) return;
                dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.ERROR, payload: { error: e } });
            });

        return () => {
            cancelToken1.cancel();
        };
    }, [filters, page]);
    return state;
}
```

```
App.js

function App() {
    const [filters, setFilters] = useState({});

    const { jobs, locations, loading, error } = useFetchJobs(filters);

    function handleParamChange(e) {
        const param = e.target.name;
        const value = e.target.value;
        setFilters((prevFilters) => {
            return { ...prevFilters, [param]: value };
        });
    }
    return(stuff)
}
```

```
SearchForm.js

<Form.Group as={Col} lg={4}>
    <Form.Label>Location</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control
        onChange={onParamChange}
        name='location'
        as='select'
        size='lg'>
        <option></option>
        {locations !== undefined &&
            locations.map((loc) => (
                <option value={loc}>{loc}</option>
            ))}
    </Form.Control>
</Form.Group>
```

Am I missing something? Thanks a lot.

[image: Example response from API call]

Comment: Please show us how you use axios in a code example.

Comment: Open the `Network` tab of your Dev Tools and/or make sure your Dev Tools `Console` shows every AJAX request that is made. When you make this request, does the URL include the `location=Austin, TX` information? If no, then it's possible you're not providing your `params` to axios properly.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I updated the post with the code. Moreover, following @therobinkim suggestion, I can see that the URL is "https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=https://jobs.github.com/positions.json&location=Austin,+TX". I would expect a question mark instead of the ampersand. Am I wrong?

Comment: why not just set the URL such that it's `https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?location=Austin, TX` to start? I wonder if axios sees the `?` in the beginning of the URL, and just attaches additional arams via `&`